# Add new record need to check if it exists with Entity Framework repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using Entity Framework repository pattern. Now I want to add new record.

```
if (question != null)
{
    var clq = new CountryLanguageQuestion
                {
                    CountryId = s.CountryId,
                    LanguageId = languageId,
                    QuestionNumber = questionNum,
                    SurveyQuestionId = s.SurveyQuestionId,
                    QuestionText = s.QuestionText
                };

    _countryLanguageQuestionRepository.Add(clq);

    _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

The question of the above code is to add the record without checking whether it exists or not. In the table, there is an identity column. CountryId, LanguageId  and SurveyQuestionId can be null. Our repository class inherits the base class.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T GetById(long Id);
    T GetById(string Id);
    T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    IQueryable<T> GetQueryable(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
}
```

So how to check the record exists already before add new record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
//Find it however you can in the context
var existing = _countryLanguageQuestionRepository.GetById(id);

if (existing == null){
     var clq = new CountryLanguageQuestion
         {
             CountryId = s.CountryId,
             LanguageId = languageId,
             QuestionNumber = questionNum,
             SurveyQuestionId = s.SurveyQuestionId,
             QuestionText = s.QuestionText
         };
     _countryLanguageQuestionRepository.Add(clq);
} else {

 //Update existing object and save it

}
```

Comment: yes, I thought about it. The thing that I am not sure is  the usage of `GetId(id)`.  What is id here? My primary key is auto identity. I have CountryId, LanguageId and SurveyQuestionId in the table. They all can be null.